# 404 page appear in every page anytime in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]

app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Pages/Login";
import ViewPurchaseOrders from "./Pages/purchases/ViewPurchaseOrders";
import ViewProductSelectionGrn from "./Pages/GRN Management/View.product.selection-grn";
import Error from "./Components/404page/Error";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path="/confirm-purchase-orders"
          component={ViewPurchaseOrders}
        />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path="/grn-product-selections"
          component={ViewProductSelectionGrn}
        />     
        <Route path="*">{Error}</Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

404 page is rendering everywhere like above attached picture. I need to fix it. I tried few ways but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: What do you mean by `every time`? When does it happen?

Comment: Are you rendering the `Error` component elsewhere in your app? It looks like it's rendering below some regular content. What is the current URL pathname for that image showing both?

Comment: @Saidamir How does one *exactly* match `path="*"`? 

Comment: Can you edit the post to include all the relevant code you are working with? I'd like to take a look at that `ProtectedRoute` component implementation. See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese It's a React Path thing, using `path="*"` will match any other route if placed add the last position in the stack of routes. Meanin, if you didn't define `/path/not-found` and browse to that page, it will render the fallback page.

Comment: @node_modules I am aware how routing works.... you can't exactly match an indeterminant path though.  Just trying to gently point out to Saidamir that simply adding the `exact` prop won't change that catch-all route.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it shows every-time below the relavent page

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The issue here is that you've managed to import the `BrowserRouter` as a `Switch`, so the `Switch` is really just a plain old router and all routes are being ***inclusively*** matched and rendered, i.e. all matching routes are rendered. Routes rendering on `path="*"` will ***always*** be matched and rendered.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Switch, // <-- whoopsies!
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

...

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch> // <-- BrowserRouter in disguise 
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path="/confirm-purchase-orders"
          component={ViewPurchaseOrders}
        />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path="/grn-product-selections"
          component={ViewProductSelectionGrn}
        />     
        <Route path="*">{Error}</Route> // <-- always rendered
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Solution

Import the `BrowserRouter` as a `Router`, then import the `Switch` and continue to render the routes into it so they are ***exclusively*** matched and rendered, i.e. only one match.

Example:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
...

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute
            path="/confirm-purchase-orders"
            component={ViewPurchaseOrders}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            path="/grn-product-selections"
            component={ViewProductSelectionGrn}
          />     
          <Route path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="*">{Error}</Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```